# SSL in Node using GoDaddy certificates using .key and .crt files

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have been looking into the solution for using ssl certificates in my node server. There are different implementations available but cannot see concrete example for godaddy certificates with .key file and .crt file.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few steps you need to follow

1- Generate csr file. Use following command

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
```

1. **key** is used as ssl secure certificate key. You don't need to share this file with anyone.
2. **csr** is used to generate certificates from godaddy

2- Log into the gGoDaddy account.

3- Open the CSR (.csr file generated using openssl command) in a text editor and copy all of the text. Paste the full CSR into the SSL enrollment form in your account.

4- It is gonna take a day to verify your domain. GoDaddy does that if you use third party domain services.

5- Now if you have bought domain from different service provider. open your domain server dashboard and update DNS records to point it to your server. (If you already did this skip this step)

6- Visit https://certs.godaddy.com/cert and download your certificates. zip file will contain 2 files. 1 with random number .crt and other with name cert_*.crt.

7- Open cert_*.crt file it will have multiple certificates in it. Now you need to split these certificates into different files like cert_1.crt cert_2.crt etc

Now use following code in node

```
var secureApp = require('../app'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    privateKey = fs.readFileSync('domain.com.key').toString(),
    certificate = fs.readFileSync('domain.com.crt').toString(),
    cert_g = fs.readFileSync('cert_g.crt').toString(),
    cert_g1 = fs.readFileSync('cert_g1.crt').toString(),
    cert_g2 = fs.readFileSync('cert_g2.crt').toString(),
    https = require('https'),
    http = require('http');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
var securePort = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '443');
secureApp.set('port', securePort);

/**
 * Create HTTPS secure server.
 */
// secure impl
var options = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate,ca: [cert_g, cert_g1, cert_g2]};
var secureServer = https.createServer(options, secureApp);
/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
secureServer.listen(securePort);
secureServer.on('error', onError);
secureSrver.on('listening', onListening);
/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */    
function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**ENJOY**

Comment: I got domain.com.key and domain.com.csr file. But from where I'll get domain.com.crt file?

Comment: 6- Visit https://certs.godaddy.com/cert and download your certificates. zip file will contain 2 files. 1 with random number .crt and other with name cert_*.crt.

Answer (score 1):

Can't we do this by setting the default certificate in

GoDaddy Cpanel -> SSL/TLS -> Manage SSL Sites

And use the .htaccess to do the redirection to what ever the port the NodeApp is running ?